# Implementing Spotify Web Api OAuth2.0 authentication and autherization using Spring boot 3 and Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am struggling from last 3 days while trying to implement an OAuth2.0 using Springboot3 and Spring Security 6.
I am making a custom provider Spotify. While registering the provider in **ClientRegistrationRepository** using **InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository** object.

Have anyone tried implementing it. It would be very helpful to have a look at the code how you have implemented it.

I am not attaching the code here because there is not much to show.

Reaching for help because there are no helpful references in the internet.

Thanks in advance

I tried implementing this using the Spring Security 6 documentation but I am not able to understand the approach there.